# Attractive Boxed Equations

Tags: equations, boxes, framed

I often used `\boxed{...}` from the AMS math package to place a box around important equations.  However, this approach often produces somewhat awkward looking output.  Consider

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
 \[
 \boxed{c_i = \sum_jA_{ij}}
 \]
 \[
 \boxed{c_i = \langle\psi|\phi\rangle}
 \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Observe that in the first case the  box looks unbalanced while in the second case could do with more padding on both the top and bottom.  What is the best way to go about this?  I know that I could use a `\phantom` but am wondering if more elegant solutions exist.

Comment: @David Hammen: I have seen world class PhD theses with boxed equations to emphasise an important equation.

Comment: @Danie: I'm curious. What makes a Ph.D. thesis world class?

Comment: @TH: Contents, contents and contents. Those theses (together with subsequent publications) that attract a lot of citations.

Comment: Danie: I'm not really sure how that's related. Most papers I read are extremely poorly typeset. Most of my coauthors don't care at all about how papers look beyond a bare minimum. And Ph.D. theses are notoriously [ugly](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19833/647).

Comment: @TH: David Hammen has commented that emphasised (boxed) equitions are only used for elementry level books. My answer was that I've seen it being used with good effect up to the highest levels of academic publishing. The issues of what is a world class thesis and bad typesetting has nothing to do with boxed equations. So what is you problem here?

Comment: @Danie: I agree with David and I don't think that a thesis counts as academic publishing (especially in that it isn't published). A journal article or (nonelementary) book that uses boxed equations would be far better evidence that it is used outside of elementary level texts. That's all. Obviously, I don't have anything invested in this. I've just never seen it done in a publication.

Comment: DavidHammen Wrong; a load of physics and mathematics textbooks use boxes (regardless of the level). 

@TH- Who says it's for publication?

Comment: @David Hammen: The book _Classical Electromagnetic Radiation, Third Edition_, by Heald and Marion (which is definitely beyond high school), make heavy use of boxed equation — a habit I realized that I could probably beneficially adopt as it highlights which equations are actually important results and which you can safely skim off. As long as it makes the text easier to read, who cares about conventions and what is considered normal?

Comment: Boxed equations also appear in Spivak's geometry books, though sparingly. Spivak's use is good, in my opinion: his books are quite expository, featuring lots of text and explanation; boxing some key equations allows his text to also be used as a reference.

Comment: I don't like boxing equations, but if you do it, please be sparing and make the box very light, perhaps a light gray.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can use the [`empheq`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/empheq) package and then define your own boxing command. It can be a standard Latex `\fbox` or a Tikz box, or any other type of box. Look at the example below. I have defined a color box (to make it more interesting) with two optional arguments for padding the space above and below the equation

```
\mybluebox[<top pad>][<bot pad>]{<contents>}
```

The `keyval` package is already loaded so you can make a fancy keyval interface, but I leave that as an exercise to the reader ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{.8, .8, 1}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}

\newlength\mytemplen
\newsavebox\mytempbox

\makeatletter
\newcommand\mybluebox{%
    \@ifnextchar[%]
       {\@mybluebox}%
       {\@mybluebox[0pt]}}

\def\@mybluebox[#1]{%
    \@ifnextchar[%]
       {\@@mybluebox[#1]}%
       {\@@mybluebox[#1][0pt]}}

\def\@@mybluebox[#1][#2]#3{
    \sbox\mytempbox{#3}%
    \mytemplen\ht\mytempbox
    \advance\mytemplen #1\relax
    \ht\mytempbox\mytemplen
    \mytemplen\dp\mytempbox
    \advance\mytemplen #2\relax
    \dp\mytempbox\mytemplen
    \colorbox{myblue}{\hspace{1em}\usebox{\mytempbox}\hspace{1em}}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{empheq}[box={\mybluebox[5pt]}]{equation*}
    c_i = \sum_j A_{ij}
\end{empheq}

\begin{empheq}[box={\mybluebox[2pt][2pt]}]{equation*}
    c_i = \langle\psi|\phi\rangle
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Will any of these work within an `align` environment where I only want to shade one of the equations.

Comment: @Peter Grill: The `\Aboxed` command form the [`mathtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package can box one line of and `aligned` environment. To change it to shadeding the line, the internal command `\@Aboxed` need to be redefined, but it is not to difficult.

Answer (score 55):

`tcolorbox` also offers several options for boxed math expressions.

`tcbhighmath` is an special box which can be used with `empheq` package, but it's also easy to declare new boxes to use with `empheq`.

Some examples with the code:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{\mymath}[1][]{%
    nobeforeafter, math upper, tcbox raise base,
    enhanced, colframe=blue!30!black,
    colback=blue!30, boxrule=1pt,
    #1}

\begin{document}
\begin{empheq}[box=\tcbhighmath]{equation*}
    c_i = \langle\psi|\phi\rangle
\end{empheq}

\tcbset{highlight math style={boxsep=5mm,colback=blue!30!red!30!white}}

\begin{empheq}[box=\tcbhighmath]{equation*}
    c_i = \langle\psi|\phi\rangle
\end{empheq}

\begin{empheq}[box=\mymath]{equation*}
    c_i = \langle\psi|\phi\rangle
\end{empheq}

\begin{empheq}[box={\mymath[colback=red!30,drop lifted shadow, sharp corners]}]{equation*}
    c_i = \langle\psi|\phi\rangle
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the last boxed equation looks super cool

Comment: @Ignasi How to add vertical margin below the box? (Space between the box and the following paragraph, etc.) Tried `after skip` but that did not work.

Comment: @blackened: This works for me: `box={\mymath[after=\vspace{1cm}]}`

Comment: @Ignasi I have added `before=\vspace{1cm}`, but it did not add vertical space above the box? Is that expected?

Comment: @blackened I don't know if it's the expected result and as I also don't know what to answer, I think it's better that you open a new question and hope that someone else can answer it.

Comment: @Ignasi If my equation is large and is occupying two lines how do I trigger next line?

Answer (score 12):

Perhaps these commands will be of some help:

```
\newcommand{\boxedeq}[2]{\begin{empheq}[box={\fboxsep=6pt\fbox}]{align}\label{#1}#2\end{empheq}}
\newcommand{\coloredeq}[2]{\begin{empheq}[box=\colorbox{lightgreen}]{align}\label{#1}#2\end{empheq}}
```

Don't forget to put

```
\usepackage{empheq} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgreen}{HTML}{90EE90}
```

in the preamble.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgreen}{HTML}{90EE90}
\newcommand{\boxedeq}[2]{\begin{empheq}[box={\fboxsep=6pt\fbox}]{align}\label{#1}#2\end{empheq}}
\newcommand{\coloredeq}[2]{\begin{empheq}[box=\colorbox{lightgreen}]{align}\label{#1}#2\end{empheq}}

\begin{document}
 \boxedeq{eq:first}{c_i = \sum_jA_{ij}}
 \coloredeq{eq:second}{c_i = \langle\psi|\phi\rangle}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Forgot to mention: the 1-st argument is a label for the equation, the 2-nd one is the emphasized equation itself.

Comment: The `framed` package is *not* required in your answer. The `xcolor` package is required (maybe with some option to access the `lightgreen` color).

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo. It appears, however, that the \empheq package is needed, see here: http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/mh/empheq.pdf

Comment: Of course `empheq` is needed. I only wanted to point out that `framed` is not needed but `xcolor` is.

Comment: How do you get a border around it?

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, I found this [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/linjaaho/how-to-make-boxed-text-with-latex) with a few options. I settled on bclogo package. Its documentation is written in French, but it looks like the more versatile option, having icons, framing, background color, title, among others.

Comment: Suppose the link is broken then your answer is useless.  Please can you add in own words a summary that answers the question? (not all people can read or understand French)