# Create environment out of eqnarray with frame box

Tags: equations, environments, framed

Could you help me to create an environment out of this code:

```
\smallskip\centering\framebox[0.9\textwidth]{
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.8\textwidth}
\begin{eqnarray}
I & = & -\mu\frac{W}{L}\int_{V_{S}}^{V_{D}} Q_{m} \cdot \ud{}V_{ch} \\
v_{g} - \Delta\phi_{i} - v_{ch} + \ln(\frac{q_{int}}{2}) & = & 4 q_{g} + \ln(q_{g}) + \ln\left( 1 + q_{g}\frac{C_{ox}}{C_{Si}} \right) \\
i & \approx & -q_{mD}^2 + q_{mD} - (-q_{mS}^2 + q_{mS})
\end{eqnarray}
\[\mathrm{where:} \quad v_{x} = \frac{V_{x}}{U_{T}},\ q_{int} = \frac{e n_{i} t_{Si}}{4 C_{ox} U_{T}},\ q_{x} = \frac{Q_{x}}{4 C_{ox} U_{T}},\ C_{Si} = \frac{\varepsilon_{Si}} {t_{Si}}\]
\medskip
\end{minipage}}
```

I have in mind something like:

```
\newenvironment{\MyMathBox}
{\smallskip\centering\framebox[0.9\textwidth]{
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.8\textwidth}}
{\medskip
\end{minipage}}}
```

The `eqnarray` block must be implementable inside the environment.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please, load the package `\usepackage{amsmath}`, change `{eqnarray}` to `{align}` and remove the 2nd `&` on each line, i.e. change `& = &` to `& =`. It will be much nicer :) Ane related question / possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20575/attractive-boxed-equations

Comment: For reference, see [`\eqnarray` vs `\align`](http://goo.gl/3R7Ln).

Comment: you might want to look at the package `mdframed`.  it's overkill, but it should probably allow you to do what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

Please always post complete documents defining all commands used (I made up something for `\ud`.

You need `lrbox` to save the contents into a box register which you can then put a frame around.  As the comments have noted it's usually better to use ams alignments than eqnarray. (Not least as it handles moving the label out of the way of large entries, as shown in the image eqnarray isn't so good at that.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{mymathbox}
{\par\smallskip\centering\begin{lrbox}{0}%
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.8\textwidth}}
{\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
\framebox[0.9\textwidth]{\usebox{0}}%
\par\medskip
\ignorespacesafterend}


\begin{document}

\def\ud{}
\begin{mymathbox}
\begin{eqnarray}
I & = & -\mu\frac{W}{L}\int_{V_{S}}^{V_{D}} Q_{m} \cdot \ud{}V_{ch} \\
v_{g} - \Delta\phi_{i} - v_{ch} + \ln(\frac{q_{int}}{2}) & = & 4 q_{g} + \ln(q_{g}) + \ln\left( 1 + q_{g}\frac{C_{ox}}{C_{Si}} \right) \\
i & \approx & -q_{mD}^2 + q_{mD} - (-q_{mS}^2 + q_{mS})
\end{eqnarray}
\end{mymathbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's almost perfect, there is just a problem with $\medskip$ command which doesn't seem to produce any result in the environment.

    \newcommand{\ud}{\mathrm{d}}

Comment: I love your example code, as it so perfectly demonstrates the shortcomings of the `eqnarray` environment.

Comment: @MichalWolodzko try it now with `\par` before each of the skips

Comment: No, it still doesn't work:
\newcommand{\ud}{\mathrm{d}}
\newenvironment{mymathbox}
{\par\smallskip\centering\begin{lrbox}{0}%
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.8\textwidth}}
{\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
\framebox[0.9\textwidth]{\usebox{0}}%
\par\medskip
\ignorespacesafterend}

Comment: well that puts a medskip, perhaps you want more space: test with changing `\medskip` to `\vspace{5cm}` to check you get a big space to following text then reduce as desired... This is space _after_ the box so doesn't show unless you add some following text

Comment: Look at the effects of environment command and a plain text:
![in environment](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8ttgw1uhkNlbnFfSHRITmVoRTg/edit?usp=sharing)
![plain code](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8ttgw1uhkNlSElKQ0pWMnRuams/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I have finally managed to solve the issue. Instead of placing `\medskip` at the very end I should have put it right before `\end{minipage}`:
`\newcommand{\ud}{\mathrm{d}}
\newenvironment{mymathbox}
{\smallskip\centering\begin{lrbox}{0}%
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.8\textwidth}}
{\medskip\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
\framebox[0.9\textwidth]{\usebox{0}}%
\smallskip
\ignorespacesafterend}`

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the solution with [TiKZ at TeXample](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/boxes-with-text-and-math/)?

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}


% Define box and box title style
\tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=red, fill=blue!20, very thick,
    rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=20pt]
\tikzstyle{fancytitle} =[fill=red, text=white]

\newcommand{\fancybox}[2][Title of the box]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){%
    \begin{minipage}{0.50\textwidth}
    #2
    \end{minipage}
};
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {#1};
\node[fancytitle, rounded corners] at (box.east) {$\clubsuit$};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}


\begin{document}

\fancybox[MyTitle]{How is that?
I can put equations here as well
\begin{align}
   E \Psi &= \hat H \Psi
\end{align}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]