# Framing an equation and equation array (boxed)

Tags: equations, boxes, framed, eqnarray

I want to nicely put equations and equations arrays inside a box or a frame.
I also like to align objects in `align` environment like in the `eqnarray` environment [r|c|l], see example below.

Working example:

```
\documentclass{article}[A4]
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newenvironment{bbox}
{\par\smallskip\centering\begin{lrbox}{0}%
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.99\textwidth}}
{\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
\framebox[0.99\textwidth]{\usebox{0}}%
\par\medskip
\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}

\title{Box test}

I want to box equations. For a simple equation:
\begin{equation} \label{1}
\boxed{ 1 + 2 = \pi - 0.14 \quad  \implies \quad \pi \in \mathbb{Q}  }
\end{equation}
Eqnarray:
\begin{eqnarray}
1 + 2 = \pi - 0.14  & \implies & \pi \in \mathbb{Q} 
\end{eqnarray}
Align:
\begin{align}
1 + 2 = \pi - 0.14  & \implies & \pi \in \mathbb{Q} 
\end{align}
I want the \texttt{align} to be aligned like \texttt{eqnarray}, how to do that?

For align and eqnarray the \texttt{boxed} won't work,
\begin{verbatim}
\begin{align}
\boxed{ 1 + 2 = \pi - 0.14  & \implies & \pi \in \mathbb{Q} }
\end{align}
\end{verbatim}
Using the environment ``bbox'' it seems to work but has some space in the top so it looks a little bit ugly:
\begin{bbox}
\begin{align}
 1 + 2 = \pi - 0.14  & \implies & \pi \in \mathbb{Q} 
\end{align}
\end{bbox}
I want it to look like equation \eqref{1}

How to do that?
```

The result:
[image: The result of this LaTeX code]

**Edit:** What about multiline equations?

```
Multiline:
\begin{align}
\Aboxed{ 1 + 2 = \pi - 0.14   \implies & \pi \in \mathbb{Q}  \\
3 \ne \pi \implies & \pi \in \mathbb{R} } 
\end{align}
```

See also:
[Create environment out of eqnarray with frame box](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100466/create-environment-out-of-eqnarray-with-frame-box)

Comment: Unrelated: `\documentclass{article}[A4]` where do you have this syntax from? Because it is incorrect and where ever you have it from ought to be updated.

Comment: Do not use `eqnarray` , the spacing at the alignment point is not correct.  To have a box around an equation in an `align` environment, you have the `\Aboxed` command defined by `mathtools`.

Comment: Off-topic: You've transferred the alignment syntax from `eqnarray` to `align`. That's a mistake. Don't write `1 + 2 = \pi - 0.14  & \implies & \pi \in \mathbb{Q}`. Instead, write `1 + 2 = \pi - 0.14  & \implies \pi \in \mathbb{Q}`. Can you spot the difference?

Comment: Yes, the extra ```&``` which aligns [rcl].