# Numbering a coloured box outside of the box

Tags: tcolorbox

I want numbered the third (blue) equation in out of box. what do I do?

[Attractive Boxed Equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20575/attractive-boxed-equations/315642#315642)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Which third blue box equation?

Answer (score 3):

You can choose:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{colframe=blue!30!black, colback=blue!30, boxrule=1pt}

\newtcbox{\mymath}[1][]{%
    nobeforeafter, math upper, tcbox raise base,
    enhanced
    #1}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[box=\mymath]{equation*}
    c_i = \langle\psi|\phi\rangle
\end{empheq}

\begin{empheq}[box=\mymath]{equation}
    c_i = \langle\psi|\phi\rangle
\end{empheq}

\begin{tcolorbox}
\begin{equation}
    c_i = \langle\psi|\phi\rangle
\end{equation}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}
\begin{equation*}
    c_i = \langle\psi|\phi\rangle
\end{equation*}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you, it work in a single file just like above. But in my file again i have an equation without numbering

Comment: @user108438    I don't want to be rude, but how can we deduce this problem from your question? would you mind to edit your question and better explain what's the problem and the desired result? You could even write the equation you want to box, or even better, include it inside a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for bad explain!
Your commands are worked in a single file correctly.
However, when I put them in my file, again I have an equation without numbering.
Maybe I used many package that are conflict together.

\begin{empheq}[box=\mymath]{equation}
‎L‎\y‎=‎\b‎‎‎  ‎‎\quad‎‎‎ ‎\quad ‎‎‎‎‎‎U\x=‎\y‎‎
\end{empheq}

Comment: @user108438 Let me insist: This description doesn't help. I don't know what packages are you using, I don't know how is written your equation, ... Please, write a Minimal working (or not) example. This means some code starting from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` including the relevant and only relevant parts of your file. In this case it seems that between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` it just need to include the failing equation. Once you have this file, include in your question and we will better help you.

Comment: I found my problem! I use xepersian package. It is a package for Persian writing.
Unfortunately, I can't remove this package, because I am writing a Persian book. In the other hand I need a numbered formula in a colored box. It is a bad situation for me.

Comment: This works perfectly with `xepersian`; I just tried it. There must be another problem with your code.