# numbering out of a colored box

Tags: xepersian

The only thing that I want is a numbering out of colored box and the position of box be in center.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=green!70, fill=green!10, very thick, rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=20pt]
\tikzstyle{fancytitle} =[fill=blue!70, text=white]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[mybox](box){%
    \begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
\begin{equation}
L y=b  \quad \quad Ux=y
\end{equation}
    \end{minipage}
};
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: How is this different from your other question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315646/numbering-a-coloured-box-outside-of-the-box?

Comment: I am working with xepersian package. This package has a problem with numbering in empheq package. As an alternative we use this example for numbering. However, the numbering is in box and we want it be in out of box. The only thing that I want is a numbering out of colored box and the position of box be in center.

Comment: I don't see `xepersian` in your document,however ;-)

Comment: many thanks for your help. I remove it in this example because I think you don't have it. One can add the following commands just before \begin{document}.  \usepackage{makeidx}‎
‎\makeindex‎‎
‎\usepackage[quickindex]{xepersian}‎‎