# newenvironment with empheq inside tcolorbox

Tags: environments, tcolorbox, empheq

I have to define a new environment doing something like that.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,empheq}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}
\begin{empheq}{align}
a=b
\end{empheq}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

This code works fine, but if I try something like testa or testb, I get errors.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,empheq}

\newenvironment{testa}{\tcolorbox\empheq{align}}{\endempheq\endtcolorbox}
\newenvironment{testb}{\tcolorbox\setkeys{EmphEqEnv}{align}\EmphEqMainEnv}{\endEmphEqMainEnv\endtcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{testa}
a=b
\end{testa}
\end{document}
```

Is there a solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to use a temporary wrapper environment for `empheq` and then 'wrap' `\tcolorboxenvironment` around it:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{empheq}

\newenvironment{testa}{%
  \empheq{align}
}{\endempheq}

\tcolorboxenvironment{testa}{colback=yellow!40!white}


\begin{document}


\begin{testa}
a=b
\end{testa}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, this is working, but in fact I need something like `\begin{testa}{gather*}a=b\end{testa} `  so the empheq parameter has to be new environment parameter. The method using `\tcolorboxenvironment` does not seem to work for that.

Comment: @MB4E: Did you ask for that argument in your question? No, you didn't.  By your comment you are changing the initial question...

Comment: I know, it was an MCV example and your answer is working in this case. I was hoping to adapt the solution to a more general situation but unfortunately it does not seem possible like that. But you right, the initial question is solved.

Comment: Nice! and if you define `testa*` and put `*` on `align*`, it works without numbering.

Answer (score 4):

I understand you want to combine `tcolorbox` with `empheq`. Instead of a `tcolorbox` which contains an `empheq` environment, you should declare an `empheq` environment with an optional parameter which defines the colorbox aspect. This combination can be declared as a `newenvironment`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{\mymath}[1][]{%
    nobeforeafter, math upper, tcbox raise base,
    enhanced, colframe=blue!30!black,
    colback=blue!30, boxrule=1pt,
    #1}

\newenvironment{testa}[1]{%
    \empheq[box={#1}]{align}}{\endempheq}

\begin{document}
\begin{empheq}[box=\mymath]{align}
    c_i &= \langle\psi|\phi\rangle \\
    d_i &= \sqrt{x^2-1}
\end{empheq}

\begin{testa}{\mymath[colback=red!30]}
    c_i &= \langle\psi|\phi\rangle \\
    d_i &= \sqrt{x^2-1}
\end{testa}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some other examples in [Attractive Boxed Equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/288326/1952)

Comment: Yes, I know this method but I really have to do things the other way.

Comment: @MB4E   Could you explain it better? What's the result you want to obtain?

Comment: Just the same result as in my first code example.

Comment: I just add a screenshot.

Comment: Something like this? `\begin{tcolorbox}[ams align]a=b\end{tcolorbox}`

Comment: @MB4E I understand that `empheq` is used to place equation numbers outside boxes, but you want them inside. Then I don't know why do you need `empheq`. `tcolorbox` with `ams ...` options can produce boxes with multiline equations with numbers inside the box and without `empheq`.

Comment: You right, but this is just a MCV example of a more complex problem. Thanks for help, perhaps I have to find another way without empheq.