# Several questions about the question "Attractive Boxed Equations"

Tags: macros, colorbox

I was reading the highest rated answer of  the question "[Attractive Boxed Equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20575/attractive-boxed-equations)",

I don't understand the main code of the answer.

There are two problems for me:

- what do the commands with prefix "\my" do? For example, "\mytempbox", "\mytemplen", etc
- What's the meaning of the symbol "@"? How to use the command "\newcommand"?

I cannot find them on LaTeX reference card...

Comment: Regarding the `@`, see this: [Why do LaTeX internal commands have an `@` in them?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6240/)

Comment: That helps a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the code you will see, for example,

```
\newlength\mytemplen
```

so `\templen` is a length.

Normally the `@` character is not a letter and cannot be used as part of a macro name but it can be made to be one within a `\makeatletter ...`\makeatother` grouping. This is normally done to have "private" macro names used only within the preamble.

Comment: Very appreciate your answer. I do know `\templen` stands for length, but the length of which object? Besides...I don't understand the definition of `\@@mybluebox`, could anyone explain it specifically?

Comment: @TziyanTschen `\templen` is just a length. It could be set to be the length of an object or the height of an object or the distance between two objects, or ...