boxed align with text to to the left (outside box) and a single tag
I've tried in many ways to reproduce the following:

Noitce - this is a box, with some multi-line math inside the box, and text appearing to the left outside the box in same line as box, at the middle. Moreoever, there's a single tag to this, appearing outisde the box.
The closest I've got is with:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{empheq}
\begin{document}
\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox, left=\textbf{BC:\quad}]{equation}
 \begin{aligned}
   u(0,t) &= 0 \\
   u(L,t) &= 0
\end{aligned}
\end{empheq}
\end{document}

which places the text inside the box.

Please make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

@Mensch done, added the usepackage

Possible duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20575/attractive-boxed-equations

The \boxed command provided by amsmath can be your friend:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \fboxsep10pt
  \text{BC: }
  \boxed{\begin{aligned}
    u(0,t) &= 0 \\
    u(L,t) &= 0
 \end{aligned}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}


